# There is no driver for Ralink chip 5360

Tags: drivers, ralink

I bought DWA-525 and it does not work

Google did not help. No one on the Internet could not get the device to work =(

lspci

```
01:06.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. Device 5360
```

I do not know what to do

uname -a

```
Linux pc 3.0.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 19 19:05:57 UTC 2012 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
```

cat /etc/lsb-release

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=oneiric
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.10"
```

I am sure that the problem is DWA-525 and chip 5360. I found many similar problems on the Internet without solving =(

Comment: Please edit your question to include some information about the system this is happening on. For example, the result of `unname -a` and `cat /etc/lsb-release` in a terminal window? It might also help to know what type of PC you are using. Can you connect to your network with a wired connection? How did you isolate the problem to the DWA-525? Are you sure the DWA-525 is just not working?

Comment: fix.
I try this card on 2 computers

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be useful to you:

https://tuxwarrior.wordpress.com/2012/10/24/como-instalar-la-tarjeta-wifi-802-11n-dlink-dwa-525-en-gnudebian/

Use this link to the driver instead of the one in the post:

http://victor2012.info/2011_0406_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO_GPL.bz2

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have the [**A2 revision of the DWA-525**](http://www.wikidevi.com/wiki/D-Link_DWA-525_rev_A2) which appears to be "less special".

If you Google around there are posts which talk about getting the earlier `A1/RT3060` revision to work with earlier versions of Ubuntu (for example, [**this blog entry**](http://steveswinsburg.wordpress.com/2011/03/12/how-to-install-a-d-link-dwa-525-wireless-network-card-in-ubuntu-10-04/)).

This is probably worth investigating, but there is no reason to expect stuff that worked for the `A1/RT3060` to also work with the `A2/RT5360`.

FWIW, you might also take a look at this post on *archlinux* [**Kernel & Hardware» new Wi Fi device Ralink rt5360**](http://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=137087).

(Sorry I can't provide any specific, useful suggestions. Lacking both experience and the hardware pretty much limits me to "hand waving".)

Comment: I read these articles before writing =(
I can send the device if you can configure it =)