# Need Drivers for D-link DWA 525 PCI Wireless adapter

Tags: wireless, drivers

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 32-Bit Edition. I have racently purchased D-link DWA 525 PCI Wireless Adapter. But i can't find the drivers for the adapter. I have been searching in internet for a while. Tried many options, including `ndiswrapper`.

When i run lspci command, it detects and shows as below.

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT5360 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R
```

My kernel version was `3.5.0-18-generic`.

After i have upgraded my kernel to `3.7.3-030703-generic` and now the device detects as

```
Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5360 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R
[1814:5360]     Subsystem: D-Link System Inc DWA-525 Wireless N 150
Desktop Adapter (rev.A2)[1186:3c05] Kernel modules: rt2800pci
```

But still there is no sign of the wireless interface in `Network Connections` window or in `iwconfig`. And the interface is not functional yet.

The output of `iwconfig` is

```
lo no wireless extensions.  
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

The output of `ifconfig` is

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:27:0e:05:5c:e1  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::227:eff:fe05:5ce1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:38317 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34741 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:38422211 (38.4 MB)  TX bytes:4955007 (4.9 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3499 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3499 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:342593 (342.5 KB)  TX bytes:342593 (342.5 KB)
```

Comment: It seems to have been answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124001/there-is-no-driver-for-ralink-chip-5360

Comment: What exactly is the output of `iwconfig` and `ifconfig -a` now? Again, include this in your answer.

Comment: Okay, I'm lost here. The kernel module is loaded, but the interface isn't listed. Haven't seen this one before.

Comment: Will try re-installing ubuntu and upgrading the kernel. My edits with the system configuration or blacklists.conf might have caused the issue. Anyways, thanks for the big help :-)

Comment: What does `dmesg | grep -iE "(firmware|network|rt2800)"` show? And you did install the firmware packages as I suggested in my answer?

Comment: dmesg | grep -iE "(firmware|network|rt2800)"
`[    0.093445] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[   12.439868] type=1400 audit(1358818787.030:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=485 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.449072] intel_rng: Firmware space is locked read-only. If you can't or
[   12.449072] intel_rng: don't want to disable this in firmware setup, and if`  I have installed firmware-proprietary package, and when i tried installing firmware package, it shows that the package is already installed.

Comment: Upgrade your kernel to 3.8 say, and it will work*emphasized text*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Background on the support in Linux

It seems that support for this has been added upstream in May 2012 (see [this](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg90131.html) on the mailing list):

> #### [PATCH] rt2x00: Add support for RT5360 based PCI devices.
>
> This chip is used at least by the D-Link DWA-525 adapter.
>
> [...]

This was committed in the kernel as [commit ccf91bd](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=commit;h=ccf91bd678d74e1e98a153539cd07a62991d6610) and has not hit the 3.5 kernel series, unfortunately, but it is in 3.6 and up:

```
$ git branch -a --contains ccf91bd
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/linux-3.6.y
  remotes/origin/linux-3.7.y
  remotes/origin/master
```

#### Steps for a solution

Now get connected to the internet first to be able to install packages. Use a wired connection for a while, buy an USB-to-Ethernet thingy if you don't have a wired connection or borrow a well-supported wireless adapter from a friend or neighbour.

Then try to install the backported kernel modules via the package [`linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic) as well as all the firmware packages: [`linux-firmware`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/linux-firmware) and [`linux-firmware-nonfree`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/linux-firmware-nonfree). You should have more luck with this version and firmware files.

If that still fails, try installing a complete 3.6 or 3.7 kernel (reboot afterwards) as I've described in my more general troubleshooting Q&A for wireless issues:

- [My WiFi adapter is not working at all, how to troubleshoot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-where-to-start-troubleshooting) (step 6: *Try the latest stable Linux kernel*)

Comment: My kernel version is the latest provided by ubuntu. its 3.5.0-22-generic. I know that backported kernals are not recommended by ubuntu. Can i still receive official updates if i install a backported kernal??

Comment: @Hari Installing a newer kernel on Quantal is unsupported, indeed. That's why I included the compat-wireless backported approach. It's in the official repositories, *is* supported and you *will* receive updates, as it's just the kernel modules for wireless devices of 3.6 being backported to the regular 3.5 kernel. :) Only in case that still doesn't work, you can try an unsupported (but still stable!) kernel. I have a strong feeling that just this single package `linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic` installation will do the job already.

Comment: I have tried installing the backported kernel. Doesn't work :-(. Upgraded my kernel to the latest stable one, 3.7.3-030703-generic. Still there is no hope :-(

Comment: This sounds impossible. It really should work out of the box with 3.6+. Could you post the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 network` in you question? Then I can verify at vendor/product ID level.

Comment: 04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5360 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R [1814:5360]
 Subsystem: D-Link System Inc DWA-525 Wireless N 150 Desktop Adapter (rev.A2) [1186:3c05]
 Kernel modules: rt2800pci.  Yeah, it detects the card. Don't know why it doesn't shows up in the system.

Comment: @Hari **This output shows it works already.** What makes you think it's not working now? And **EDIT** your question with *all new information*! Include what makes you believe it doesn't show up. As it does show up.

Comment: @Hari *EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT* your question. This site is not a discussion forum.